# Trace class of the position autocorrelation function

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, correlation-functions, trace

Let us consider a quantum system of $N$ distinguishable particles, and let us tag the configuration $\hat q_j$ of one of those.
I am interested in checking whether the position auto-correlation function in a thermal ensemble
\begin{equation}
C(t)=\frac 1 {Z_\beta}\mathrm{Tr}\left\{e^{-\beta \hat H}\hat q_j e^{i\hat H t}\hat q_j e^{-i\hat H t}\right\}
\end{equation} 
is trace class. Here $\beta$ denotes the inverse temperature.

The canonical density is trace class, as it is bounded on the Hilbert space, self-adjoint and positive. What about the other terms? I know that $\hat q_j$ is non bounded and Hermitian, while $e^{i\hat H t }$ is bounded and not Hermitian.

Comment: The reasons you provide  to justify the fact that $e^{-\beta H}$ is trace class are by no means sufficient. I suspect that you are quantizing in a finite box where the spectrum of $H$ is discrete and increases sufficiently fast to assure the trace class property. In a box the position operator is bounded so that the complete product of five operstors  is trace-class as well.

Comment: Thanks for the point. Indeed my system is located in a bounded volume, hence its energy eigenvalues are discrete. At this point I wonder, could one show that for any confined geometry $\sum_{n}<E_n|e^{-\beta \hat H}|E_n><+\infty$ ?While this is true for e.g. for a particle in a box or a harmonic oscillator, I would not now how to prove it for any (nonlinear) system in a confined geometry whose energy levels cannot be exactly computed

Comment: This can help https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weyl_law